# Sorting a list in python from the second element on

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort a list but I want it to be sorted excluding the first element.

For example:

```
a = ['T', 4, 2, 1, 3]
```

Now I want the list to be sorted but the first element should stay in its place:

```
a = ['T', 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I know this can be done by using a sorting algorithm but is there a one line way to do it or a more *pythonic* way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do so by slice assignment where you replace a slice of `a` with a sorted slice of `a`:

```
>>> a = ['T',4,2,1,3]
>>> a[1:] = sorted(a[1:])
>>> a
['T', 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Can you explain assignment to a slice?

Comment: @PeterWood I added a line describing it, OP can search the term on their own to find answers explaining it in great detail (much better than I can).

Answer (score 3):

You could slice it, sort the trailing slice and concatenate it afterwards:

```
>>> a = a[:1] + sorted(a[1:])
>>> a
['T', 1, 2, 3, 4]
```