# How to order a list of list in python from the second element on?

Tags: python, list, sorting

in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770650/sorting-a-list-in-python-from-the-second-element-on) was asked how to "Sorting a list in python from the second element on".

Is there any way to sort a list of lists in the same way? Example:

```
my_list = [
  ["1234", "aaa", "ccc", "bbb"],
  ["2332", "ggg", "bbb", "hhh"],
  ["4627", "ggg", "aaa", "hhh"],
  ["5332", "zzz", "vbb", "hhs"]
]
```

in

```
my_list = [
  ["1234", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc"],
  ["4627", "aaa", "ggg", "hhh"],
  ["2332", "bbb", "ggg", "hhh"],
  ["5332", "hhs", "vbb", "zzz"]
]
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238196/how-does-the-key-argument-in-pythons-sorted-function-work

Comment: How is your 2D list sorted? I don't get your logic from example.

Comment: I'm sorry, edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand your question right, you want to sort every item in list from second element, and then the whole list according second element:

```
my_list = [
  ["1234", "aaa", "ccc", "bbb"],
  ["2332", "ggg", "bbb", "hhh"],
  ["4627", "ggg", "aaa", "hhh"],
  ["5332", "zzz", "vbb", "hhs"]
]

my_list = sorted([[f, *sorted(v)] for f, *v in my_list], key=lambda k: k[1])

from pprint import pprint
pprint(my_list)
```

Prints:

```
[['1234', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
 ['4627', 'aaa', 'ggg', 'hhh'],
 ['2332', 'bbb', 'ggg', 'hhh'],
 ['5332', 'hhs', 'vbb', 'zzz']]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, even if the question was asked in an unclear way. I would like to specify that in my case I changed the code to `my_list = sorted([[f, *sorted(v)] for f, *v in my_list], key=lambda k: k[1:])` to order on all items and not just on the second.